# How to detach from EventToCommandBehavior?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I appear to be experiencing duplicate events whilst using the EventToCommandBehavior class I got from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior

I'm following an MVVM pattern so in my XAML I have this:

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding FilterOptions.IsActive}"
        HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <Switch.Behaviors>
        <behaviour:EventToCommandBehaviour EventName="Toggled" Command="{Binding OnActiveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding FilterOptions.IsActive}" />
    </Switch.Behaviors>
</Switch>
```

In my ViewModel I have this:

```
public ICommand OnActiveCommand => new Command<Boolean>(OnActive);
public ICommand OnDiscontinuedCommand => new Command<Boolean>(OnDiscontinued);

private void OnDiscontinued(Boolean value) {
    Debug.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    if (!value) {
        FilterOptions.IsActive = false;
    }
}

private void OnActive(Boolean value) {
    Debug.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    if (!value) {
        FilterOptions.IsDiscontinued = false;
    }
}
```

It attaches perfectly and when I interact with the switches, the commands are called as expected. However, I have noticed if I close the current page and go back to it, when I interact with any of the switches, the commands are duplicated?

I've put a breakpoint on OnDetachingFrom() (in BahviourBase.cs) and on DeregisterEvent() (in EventToCommandBehaviour.cs) assuming these may be called if I close the page? Both shown below:

**BahviourBase.cs**

```
public class BehaviourBase<T> : Behavior<T> where T : BindableObject {
    public T AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(T bindable) {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        AssociatedObject = bindable;

        if (bindable.BindingContext != null) {
            BindingContext = bindable.BindingContext;
        }

        bindable.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(T bindable) {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.BindingContextChanged -= OnBindingContextChanged;
        AssociatedObject = null;
    }

    void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        OnBindingContextChanged();
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged() {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        BindingContext = AssociatedObject.BindingContext;
    }
}
```

**EventToCommandBehaviour.cs**

```
public class EventToCommandBehaviour : BehaviourBase<View> {
    Delegate eventHandler;

    public static readonly BindableProperty EventNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create("EventName", typeof(string), typeof(EventToCommandBehaviour), null, propertyChanged: OnEventNameChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EventToCommandBehaviour), null);
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(EventToCommandBehaviour), null);
    public static readonly BindableProperty InputConverterProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Converter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(EventToCommandBehaviour), null);

    public string EventName {
        get { return (string)GetValue(EventNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EventNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public ICommand Command {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter {
        get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public IValueConverter Converter {
        get { return (IValueConverter)GetValue(InputConverterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputConverterProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(View bindable) {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        RegisterEvent(EventName);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(View bindable) {
        DeregisterEvent(EventName);
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
    }

    void RegisterEvent(string name) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) {
            return;
        }

        EventInfo eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(name);
        if (eventInfo == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("EventToCommandBehavior: Can't register the '{0}' event.", EventName));
        }
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(EventToCommandBehaviour).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("OnEvent");
        eventHandler = methodInfo.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this);
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(AssociatedObject, eventHandler);
    }

    void DeregisterEvent(string name) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) {
            return;
        }

        if (eventHandler == null) {
            return;
        }
        EventInfo eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(name);
        if (eventInfo == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("EventToCommandBehavior: Can't de-register the '{0}' event.", EventName));
        }
        eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(AssociatedObject, eventHandler);
        eventHandler = null;
    }

    void OnEvent(object sender, object eventArgs) {
        if (Command == null) {
            return;
        }

        object resolvedParameter;
        if (CommandParameter != null) {
            resolvedParameter = CommandParameter;
        } else if (Converter != null) {
            resolvedParameter = Converter.Convert(eventArgs, typeof(object), null, null);
        } else {
            resolvedParameter = eventArgs;
        }

        if (Command.CanExecute(resolvedParameter)) {
            Command.Execute(resolvedParameter);
        }
    }

    static void OnEventNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue) {
        var behavior = (EventToCommandBehaviour)bindable;
        if (behavior.AssociatedObject == null) {
            return;
        }

        string oldEventName = (string)oldValue;
        string newEventName = (string)newValue;

        behavior.DeregisterEvent(oldEventName);
        behavior.RegisterEvent(newEventName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, `the commands are duplicated` means invoked twice each tapping it ?

Comment: "assuming these may be called if I close the page?" - did they get called?

Comment: Junior Jiang MSFT, They do get invoked twice, correct. And iSpain17, if I were to go back in my stack thus removing the page my assumption is that the detach method would be called. But it does not.

Comment: @MattVon It's strange. Which version of Xamarin Forms in project , and could you show a sample link , I will check it .

Comment: Looking at the post from @Benl, this may be my solution. If it fails I can provide a sample later on in the day.

Comment: @MattVon Okey, if solved remember to mark it .

Answer (score 2):

**Removing behavior explicitly from control**

[Removing a Behavior from a Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/creating#removing-a-behavior-from-a-control) states:

> The `OnDetachingFrom` method is fired when a behavior is removed from a control, and is used to perform any required cleanup such as unsubscribing from an event to prevent a memory leak. However, behaviors are not implicitly removed from controls unless the control's `Behaviors` collection is modified by a `Remove` or `Clear` method.
>
> ...
>
> In addition, note that behaviors are not implicitly removed from controls when pages are popped from the navigation stack. Instead, they must be explicitly removed prior to pages going out of scope.

To make `OnDetachingFrom` being invoked, either remove the specific behavior or clear the behavior collection from the control.

Example for Page with an `Entry` named `entry`:

Page.xaml:

```
<Entry x:Name="entry" ...
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior ...
```

Page.cs.xaml:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    //var toRemove = entry.Behaviors.FirstOrDefault(b => b is EventToCommandBehavior);
    //if (toRemove != null)
    //{
    //    entry.Behaviors.Remove(toRemove);
    //}

    entry.Behaviors.Clear();
}
```

**Modifying BehaviorBase.cs and BindingContext**

In `BehavorBase.cs` replace the `void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` method (based on the [Xamarin Forms Behavior Cleanup Example](https://github.com/hartez/XFBehaviorCleanupExample)):

```
void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnBindingContextChanged();

    var visualElement = sender as VisualElement;
    if (visualElement == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (visualElement.BindingContext == null)
    {
        OnDetachingFrom(visualElement);
    }
}
```

`OnDisappearing` and `OnAppearing`:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    // This will trigger behavior cleanup
    // MyListView.ItemsSource = null;
    this.BindingContext = null;
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    
    //MyListView.ItemsSource = list; //in the page constructor in the sample above

    // bind your viewmodel (set the BindingContext)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this Benl! I missed this page entirely, I'll give this a shot.

Comment: I was wondering, as I will have multiple switches in a single view (some may even be inside a ListView), is there an easy way to label a parent control and close all child behaviours that way?

Comment: A visualtreehelper like this one [FindVisualChildren](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18599/visual-tree-helper) returns a list of items that can be used to remove the behaviors. Example: `var pickerList = MyExtensions.FindVisualChildren<Picker>(LayoutRoot, listView);` //LayoutRoot is a named parent layout of the named ListView listView.

Comment: So I've managed to find a solution thanks to yourself, I may have to find the additional link I found, as the one you sourced helped but not for myself completely. I still have one slight hiccup right now though. I'm trying to detach from my events in a ListView, which partially works. But at the moment I'm successfully detaching any switches found in group headers but having no luck in the body of the item.